# Problems of Returning functions from a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, return, return-value

I'm now studying a course
There's one question I don't understand

What is the output of below code using closure?

```js
function createPlayer() {
  let score = 0;

  function add(amount) {
    score = score + amount;
  }

  function report(label) {
    console.log(label, score);
  }

  return {
    score,
    add,
    report,
  };
}

let player1 = createPlayer();
let player2 = createPlayer();

player1.add(1);
player2.add(2);

console.log('1:', player1.score);
console.log('2:', player2.score);

player1.report('3:');
player2.report('4:');
```

My choice is

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 1
4: 2
```

However , the correct answer is

```
1: 0
2: 0
3: 1
4: 2
```

May I ask why player1.score & player2.score are still 0 after the function player1.add(1) & player2.add(2) are called ? Wouldn't the the score be increased by 1 and 2 ?

Please help me solve the problems

Comment: You copy the values from the variables to the object and return the object before you change the values of the variables. Numbers are copied by value, they aren't references.

Comment: `let score` isn't linked to `{ score, ... }`. You're returning an object with the current value of `score`, not "the variable".

Comment: Because the `player1.score` property is a different thing than the `let score` variable. Only one of them is updated.

Comment: You can replace score by a getScore function which will return the value of score inside of the closure

Comment: i still dont understand..

Comment: @Andy — Write the number 0 on a blackboard. (`let score = 0;`). Take a photo of it and email it to a friend (`return { score }`). Now erase the 0 and write 1 instead (`core = score + amount`). Now look at the photo. It still shows 0.